# Multiple Dynamic created events with Handlers! (ID issue)

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, event-handling, dynamic-controls

I have a very dynamic web app that is dynamically created controls at run-time.

Here is the first needed part of my code to solve my issue.

This is in a for loop, essentially it creates multiple checkbox's with ID's and event handlers.

```
// All I am doing here is incrementing our session counter so we can increment our ID
int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
id++;
Session["id"] = id;

// Now I create my checkbox
chkDynamic = new CheckBox();
chkDynamic.Text = "hey";
string chk = "chk" + id.ToString();

chkDynamic.ID = chk;
chkDynamic.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkDynamic_CheckedChanged);
Panel1.Controls.Add(chkDynamic);
```

This next section is our custom even handler

```
protected void chkDynamic_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (((CheckBox)sender).Checked)
            Response.Write("you checked the checkbox :" + this.chkDynamic.ID);
        else
            Response.Write("checkbox is not checked");
    }
```

The thing that strikes me as ODD.  Is that this will work perfectly fine if I change:

```
string chk = "chk" + id.ToString();
```

To:

```
string chk = "chk";
```

But then of course we run into "multiple controls with the same ID"

My problem is getting this to work with unique ID's!  Another bit of ODD information that may help.  If I take it out of a loop, and manually add a checkbox with a different ID it works as well.  This is mind boggling :(

```
    chkDynamic = new CheckBox();
    chkDynamic.Text = "hey";
   // string chk = "chk" + id.ToString();

    chkDynamic.ID = "hey1";
    chkDynamic.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkDynamic_CheckedChanged);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(chkDynamic);

    chkDynamic = new CheckBox();
    chkDynamic.Text = "hey";
   // string chk = "chk" + id.ToString();

    chkDynamic.ID = "hey2";
    chkDynamic.CheckedChanged += new EventHandler(chkDynamic_CheckedChanged);
    Panel1.Controls.Add(chkDynamic);
```

I have also debugged my program, and the values stored in the Session["id"] are not null nor corrupt.  Always holding value 0 and up!

Thanks for looking guys / gals.  I'm really stuck on this!

PS - Sorry.  There are no errors.  The events just do not fire unless I hard code the ID's.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Or are they just not rendering?

Comment: @csharpsi Sorry.  They're are no errors.  The events just do not fire unless I hard code the ID's.

Comment: The reason is probably because each post back you are assigning different Id's - the controls must get re-assigned the same id's each postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forget to reset the sesssion("ID"), so when the page posts back the checkboxes are recreated with new ids. Since the checkbox-es are recreated on every postback, they need to have the same ID every time and if they don't they are percepted as new controls and therefor the event handler is not called.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply.  But they are definatly getting reset. First round threw on debug the session ID = 0. Second round thew the session ID = 1.  Also I would get an aspx error at runtime indicating multiple unique ID's and the page wouldn't render.  But it does!

Comment: No, you misunderstood me. Every time you create these checkboxex, they HAVE TO have the SAME id as in the previous page lifecycle. In my opinion you could remove the Session["ID"], and simply use a local variable set to 0 in the beggining.

Comment: Ah.  Your exactly right.  Is there anyway to reset that session("ID")?

The local variable will be reset everytime a postback happens, unless its defined in the !Page.IsPostBack. But then the rest of the application has no scope to the variable :(

Comment: Well, it depends on why you need that session variable. But you could just keep your code and replace: 
    int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["id"]);
with:
    int id = 0;
and keep the rest, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `AutoPostBack` property of your checkboxes to `true`?

Comment: Just added chkDynamoc.AutoPoastBack = true but this did not fix my problem :(